# Custom ILogger scope values not working as expected

Tags: azure-functions, ilogger

I'm missing something here as the numerous articles suggest it should work.  The plan will be to create a custom logger implementation so I can store various values in a structured way.

However, for now the basics don't seem to work.

I'm trying to using scopes within `ILogger` to set certain values e.g. `transactionId`.

I'm using Azure Functions.  In the startup I've added

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
```

Which works fine.  In the function I'm trying this..

```
public class Test_Http
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public Test_Http(ILogger<TestHttp> log)
    {
        this.logger = log;
    }


    [FunctionName("TestHttp")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // This works fine, SomeId is replace.
        // When using a custom logger I can see 2 values in the state.
        logger.LogInformation("Message '{SomeId}'", "TheID");


        using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["SomeId"] = "SOME ID"
        }))
        {
            // SomeId is not replaced as I would expect.
            // State in a custom logger contains a single value.
            logger.LogInformation("A log from within scope {SomeId}");
        }

    }
}
```

What am I missing?!

Thanks.

Comment: which doc mentions it? As far as I know, it only add a property to the information message when using logger.BeginScope(). Unless you specify the property in logger.LogInformation method like logger.LogInformation("A log from within scope {SomeId}","the value").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, when using a `dictionary type` inside `logger.BeginScope` method, then the `key-value pair` in the collection is added to the application insights telemetry as `custom properties`(doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#logging-scopes)). It will not replace the `{SomeId}` in your example.

If you want to replace it, you need to explicitly add a value in `logger.LogInformation` method. For example:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> a = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            //SomeId only adds as a custom property for telemetry data.
            ["SomeId"] = "SOME ID"
        };

        using (logger.BeginScope(a))
        {
            //you need to explicitly add a value to replace {SomeId}
            logger.LogInformation("A log from within scope {SomeId}",a.Values.First());
        }
```

Comment: OK thanks.  I didn't read it anywhere specifically, but (to me at least) it did seem to be implied.  Also, that's how Serilog works, so that probably influenced my assumption!